# How to export an Excel file from a dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to make an excel file from a dictionary that I have.
It simply is an dictionary with information about images, like the size, how many paragraphs, how many words, etc.

Let's say the dictionary is:

```
{'Screenshot_1.jpg': {'SIZE': 214649, 
                      'HEIGHT': 664, 
                      'WIDTH': 1351, 
                      'PARAGRAPHS': 3, 
                      'WORDS': 427, 
                      'Paragraph1': {'Words': 28}, 
                      'Paragraph2': {'Words': 0}, 
                      'Paragraph3': {'Words': 0}},
 'Screenshot_2.jpg': {'SIZE': 168279,  
                      'HEIGHT': 664, 
                      'WIDTH': 1348, 
                      'PARAGRAPHS': 2, 
                      'WORDS': 1839,  
                      'Paragraph1': {'Words': 57}, 
                      'Paragraph2': {'Words': 9}}}
```

The code that I used to extract this dictionary to a csv/excel file it is:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
dict1 = {'Screenshot_1.jpg': {'SIZE': 214649, 'HEIGHT': 664, 'WIDTH': 1351, 'PARAGRAPHS': 3, 'WORDS': 427, 'Paragraph1': {'Words': 28}, 'Paragraph2': {'Words': 0}, 'Paragraph3': {'Words': 0}}, 'Screenshot_2.jpg': {'SIZE': 168279, 'HEIGHT': 664, 'WIDTH': 1348, 'PARAGRAPHS': 2, 'WORDS': 1839, 'Paragraph1': {'Words': 57}, 'Paragraph2': {'Words': 9}}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1, index=[0])
df = (df.T)
print(df)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

And it works well but it gives me this [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TCSA.jpg).

But I want it to give results in columns and rows [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODDVx.jpg) .

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` has `to_csv` function to export dataframe as a .csv file, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'Screenshot_1.jpg': {'SIZE': 214649, 'HEIGHT': 664, 'WIDTH': 1351, 'PARAGRAPHS': 3, 'WORDS': 427,
                              'Paragraph1': {'Words': 28}, 'Paragraph2': {'Words': 0}, 'Paragraph3': {'Words': 0}},
         'Screenshot_2.jpg': {'SIZE': 168279, 'HEIGHT': 664, 'WIDTH': 1348, 'PARAGRAPHS': 2, 'WORDS': 1839,
                              'Paragraph1': {'Words': 57}, 'Paragraph2': {'Words': 9}}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1)
df = df.T
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Resul is look like (when I opened it using MS Excel):
[image]

Comment: @titimar It would be great if you accent my answer in case that you're satisfied :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want those columns you specified, you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).T
df = df.loc[:,"SIZE":"PARAGRAPHS"]
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

If you want it the excel you can replace the last line with
`df.to_excel('output.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to drop columns just add key name in drop list

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Screenshot_1.jpg': {'SIZE': 214649, 'HEIGHT': 664, 'WIDTH': 1351, 'PARAGRAPHS': 3, 'WORDS': 427, 'Paragraph1': {'Words': 28}, 'Paragraph2': {'Words': 0}, 'Paragraph3': {'Words': 0}}, 'Screenshot_2.jpg': {'SIZE': 168279, 'HEIGHT': 664, 'WIDTH': 1348, 'PARAGRAPHS': 2, 'WORDS': 1839, 'Paragraph1': {'Words': 57}, 'Paragraph2': {'Words': 9}}}


dropList = ['Paragraph1','Paragraph2']
 for k in data.keys():
     for j in dropList:
         data[k].pop(j)
pdDict = pd.DataFrame(data)
pdDict = pdDict.T
pdDict.to_csv("file.csv")
```

for excel use `pdDict.to_excel("file.xlsx")`